# Record network traffic to plain text similar to nettop

Tags: mac, network, data

I have been monitoring my network traffic by app with

```bsh
nettop -P
```

The result is similar to this:

```
               interface   state   bytes_in    bytes_out   rx_dupe    rx_ooo     re-tx   rtt_avg
syslogd.50                            0 B         57 KiB     0 B       0 B       0 B
systemstats.63                        0 B          0 B       0 B       0 B       0 B
configd.65                            0 B          0 B       0 B       0 B       0 B
...
```

If I quit an application, I loses the record of its traffic.

I would like a method to record network upload and download traffic of all applications that launched between startup and shutdown. Does that exist?

Comment: You can do what you want by redirecting the output to a text file using `>` and pushing it to the background with `&`.  `nettop -P > file.txt &`. However this is a rudimentary tool that redraws the screen which means your text file will be next to useless.  Use a proper monitoring utility like [vnStat](https://humdi.net/vnstat/)

Comment: I was able to redirect `nettop` but couldn't understand how to parse the text. I tested the `vnStat` tool and I couldn't separate traffic numbers by process with [the manual](https://humdi.net/vnstat/man/vnstat.html). Are you able to do it?